# Updating devices with embedded Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, updates

I am looking to do a full review of tools that can help update devices with Linux. I've come across Resin.io which is a container-based approach for updating applications. Some competitors of Resin.io include Mender.io, swupdate, OStree, RAUC. Are there any others that I am missing specifically for Linux devices?

Comment: It's not clear what "device" does exactly mean to you. Hardware?

Comment: Updating a board's firmware/software.

Comment: Your comment didn't clarify even a bit of this.

Comment: there is hawkbit, but ive never looked into it: https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/hawkbit

and lennart poettering just recently proposed a combination of systemd, casync and mkosi:http://0pointer.net/blog/mkosi-a-tool-for-generating-os-images.html

Comment: Hawkbit is not a competitor of these. It is a provider for these update clients. You can use RAUC as an updater client and hawkbit as an update server to provide RAUC a bundle.

Comment: have you written a review on these? Id be interested in reading